Botan library container Botan::secure_vector<uint8_t> Vs. std::vector<uint8_t>
In Botan's example code, I see various ways of creating keys and IV/nonce which include a combination of either Botan::secure_vector<uint8_t> OR std::vector<uint8_t>.
Primarily the keys are constructed using std::vector and IV is constructed using secure_vector. I would assume the keys also need to be constructed with secure_vector given what the documentation says about using secure_vector in place of std::vector.
Essentially I am asking what are the use cases of using either one of those container types (secvec vs normal vector) in our own application code.

Useful link: https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/api_ref/secmem.html

also useful: you can convert between them using lock(std::vector) and unlock(Botan::vector). you can see more in the code https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/base/secmem.h

Thanks for that link. I did read that part of the AP ref but the src examples pretty much always create keys with regular std::vector so I was curious about why that is so. @honzaik Thanks for the pointer. That conversion will definitely come handy.
